# Need to find where 2 objects are located in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to get 2 objects locations, so I can make the AI I coded to not walk through walls. My problem is that it's ignoring any extra if statements when I add them to the script.

```
function findEntities() { //Function for finding the players position and setting the playerLeft and playerTop variables
    playerLeft = parseInt(player.style.left);
    playerTop = parseInt(player.style.top);
    enemyLeft = parseInt(enemy.style.left);
    enemyTop = parseInt(enemy.style.top);
    WallLeft = parseInt(wall.style.left);
    WallTop = parseInt(wall.style.top);
    chooseMovement();
    setTimeout(findEntities, 1000) //starting a loop.
}
findEntities();
function chooseMovement() { //Chooses the direction to move, moves on X-axis first, then Y-axis
    if((playerLeft - 64) > enemyLeft) || ((WallLeft - 64) != enemyLeft) {
        Right();
    } else if((playerLeft + 64) < enemyLeft) {
        Left();
    } else if((playerTop + 64) < enemyTop) {
        Up();
    } else if((playerTop - 64) > enemyTop) {
        Down();
    } else {
        damagePlayer();
}}

function Right() { //Moves the enemy right
    enemy.style.left = parseInt(enemy.style.left) + 64;
    enemyLeft += 64;
}
function Left() { //Moves the enemy left
    enemy.style.left = parseInt(enemy.style.left) - 64;
    enemyLeft -= 64;
}
function Up() { //Moves the enemy up
    enemy.style.top = parseInt(enemy.style.top) - 64;
    enemyTop -= 64;
}
function Down() { //Moves the enemy down
    enemy.style.top = parseInt(enemy.style.top) + 64;
    enemyTop += 64;
}
```

Comment: `if((playerLeft - 64) > enemyLeft) || ((WallLeft - 64) != enemyLeft)` — That’s a syntax error. And please use `const` or `let` and scope your variables properly; that would avoid several potential problems. _“it's ignoring any extra if statements”_ — No, nothing is ignored. What, specifically, is the problem?

Comment: could you update the code with an example of an additional statement that it is ignoring?

Comment: My problem is it's ignoring the 
```
 if((playerLeft - 64) > enemyLeft) || ((WallLeft - 64) != enemyLeft) {
  Right();
```
Even when I changed the Or to another nested if statement

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The syntax is invalid. A nested `if` statement and an `||` are not equivalent. Consider the logic of this function carefully.

Comment: @SebastianSimon wait what???? this prints "this works": https://git.io/JtO2Q

Comment: @Brice Look at the parentheses carefully. It says `if ( (`…`)`…`) || ( (`…`)`…`)`. That is not valid. Yours is `if ( (`…`) || (`…`) )`, which, of course, is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure what exactly is giving you issues, but one thought is to maybe define the "checks" as their own function, for example:

```
function chooseMovement() { 
 if(checkMoveRight()) {
    Right();
 } else if((playerLeft + 64) < enemyLeft) {
    Left();
 } else if((playerTop + 64) < enemyTop) {
    Up();
 } else if((playerTop - 64) > enemyTop) {
    Down();
 } else {
    damagePlayer();
 }
}

function checkMoveRight(){
  if(playerLeft - 64 > enemyLeft){ return true }
  if(WallLeft - 64 != enemyLeft){ return true }
  return false
}
```

This introduces it's own set of problems when it comes to complexity and state and what not but extracting things out into their own definitions rather than trying to have everything exist in the primary/singular if/else call thread might be useful.